# Solomon Object Model

Tags: .net, vb.net

Working on an old VB.Net 2005 application that does Solomon 7.0 automation integration. I believe I have the correct references setup. I'm able to instantiate Application variable and the invoice screen as expected. However when I try to assign values to some of the controls on the screen the controls do not except the value. When I further interrogate the control, the property of the control is Enabled = False. I've tried to set the control Enabled property to True.

I'm thinking possibly, references are not correct or I'm missing a step where I tell the Invoice form that it is in edit mode.

```
Dim MyApp As New Microsoft.Dynamics.SL.ObjectModel.SIVApplication()
MyApp = MyToolbar.StartApplication(sINVOICE_ENTRY)
```